# Show two overflow menu in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an existing setup working where overflow menu is shown in the toolbar. What I want to do is show two menus, one for the toolbar and one to be used inside the fragment kind of like gmail app

[image: one menu for the taskbar/toolbar and one for the email message]

If someone can point me out to a tutorial for this, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use the Popup Menu. Take a look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) component. It allows you to duplicate the ActionBar behavior anywhere. Here's a similar question that solves that specific problem: [How to set menu to Toolbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648913/how-to-set-menu-to-toolbar-in-android)

Also watch out for this: [Toolbar.inflateMenu seems to do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511981/toolbar-inflatemenu-seems-to-do-nothing)

Inflate the menu from zero via `Toolbar#inflateMenu(int)` and update it via `Toolbar#getMenu()`

Comment: I am already able to see the menu in toolbar, I want another menu to be seen in the fragment/activity

Comment: Right, just use another Toolbar?