# missing action bar in empty activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to learn how to work with toolbar in android and trying to add menu in action bar but when I ran my previews started project, noticed that default empty activity menu bar now missing! I don't know why this happened.

here is my MainActivity.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ir.cupcode.artin.contact.MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have this block of code for menu bar in MainActivity.java :

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menubar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

here is my menubar.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_test"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings">
</item>
```

In addition I get an error for using `android:showAsAction="always"` that says should use app:showAsAction with the appcombat library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_appicon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Are you extending your activity to `AppcompatActivity`?

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: @SripadRaj by default its extended! `  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: So have you added the `Appcompat` lib to your proj? If not, add it. Change the `android:showAsAction="always"` to `app:showAsAction`

Comment: @sasikumar I posted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your app theme

```
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

into

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Awesome ! solved my problem but could you tell me why my application was set to   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"?!

Answer (score 1):

for android studio flamingo (2022.2.1):

open "manifest.xml"

replace:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MenuDemo"
```

with:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you theme from :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

to :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a toolbar in your MainActivity.xml, inside your Relative Layout and over your ListView. You can create a new file for that like naming it 'Toolbar.xml' and creating the content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:title="Main Activity"/>
```

then include it in your MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ir.cupcode.artin.contact.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" id="@+id/toolbar">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you have to instantiate the toolbar in your app first. Like this:

```
yourToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.yourToolbar);
setSupportActionbar(yourToolbar);
```

You can also check out these forums.

[Toolbar.inflateMenu seems to do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511981/toolbar-inflatemenu-seems-to-do-nothing)

[How to set menu to Toolbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648913/how-to-set-menu-to-toolbar-in-android)

Hope this helps!